# How would I incorporate colliderect into a Snake Game?

Tags: python, pygame

Let me start off by saying I'm not an amazing coder so the code is not the prettiest. I'm working on a really basic version of snake right now. Currently I'm stumped on the collision between the snake and the food. (x,y for snake and foodx, foody for the food). The Collision Detection is just flat out not working right now and I can't figure out what is wrong with it. Thanks in advance for any help.
Please keep it as simple as possible, don't want to get into any classes as I have no idea how to use those yet.

Edit: Sorry, English is not my first language. The code is functional right now. The collision and food generation after the collision with the food is not working.

```
import pygame
import sys
import random
import math
import time

pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))

red=(255,0,0)
blue=(0,0,255)
green=(0,255,0)
black=(0,0,0)

block1=1
block2=0

count=0

screen.fill(black)


randStart=random.randint(0,25)

x=randStart*20
y=randStart*20
xd=20
yd=0

foodx=random.randint(0,480)
foody=random.randint(0,480)

snakecol=pygame.Rect(x,y,20,20)
foodcol=pygame.Rect(foodx,foody,20,20)




done=False
while not done:
    screen.fill(black)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True


#controls

    if block1==1:
        if(pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_a]):
            yd=0
            xd=-20
            block1=0
            block2=1

    if block1==1:
        if(pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_d]):
            yd=0
            xd=20
            block1=0
            block2=1
    if block2==1:        
        if(pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_w]):
            xd=0
            yd=-20
            block1=1
            block2=0
    if block2==1:
        if(pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_s]):
            xd=0
            yd=20
            block1=1
            block2=0


#stop moving paddle

    if x<-20:
        x=500
    if x>500:
        x=-20
    if y<-20:
        y=500
    if y>500:
        y=-20

#food
    if snakecol.colliderect(foodcol):
        foodx=random.randint(0,480)
        foody=random.randint(0,480)





    x=x+xd
    y=y+yd



    pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,255,255),(foodx,foody,20,20),0)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,255,255),(x,y,20,20),0)
    pygame.display.flip()



    time.sleep(0.4)
    count+=1
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: You've stated "is just flat out not working right now". You'll get a much better response if you show us how its not working. Give us an example of what you do / expect and what actually happens. The more effort you put into you question, the more you'll receive in your answers. Also, leveraging Object Orientated Programming will probably save you on debug / test time 100x fold over.

Comment: My bad, really stressed out right now. I've edited the question.

Comment: I don't think you followed my advice at all, you just reiterated that the collision is not working. How isn't it working? What x,y location was the snake at and the food at when a collision was supposed to take place (I assume the snake and food were at the same, but state that). What happened when the collision failed? What should happen? You need to provide a small sample we can run to help you. Being stressed is ok but you're not going to find many people are willing to debug your entire program for you.

Comment: I'm not asking for my entire program to be debugged, just the collidrect :/

Comment: I'm not going to sit here and argue with you.  Please reread my comments.  See the suggests and try to implement them.  Provide what's happening,  what you expect.  Your thoughts.  A small test we can run.  I'm done replying to this.  Goodluck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change x=x+xd to snakecol.x += xd and the same for the y part. Then in the draw part use snakecol as the rect rather than x,y,20,20 as now.  The problem is that you never update the snake rect position. Sorry for formatting, am at work and on tablet.

Comment: Update: Got it working after a bit of tweaking. Thank you so much.